# Just upgraded to Lubuntu 15.04 and Lexmark printer Pro 715 stopped working

Tags: printing, 15.04

I just upgraded to Lubuntu 15.04. How do I install my Lexmark Printer?  I am new to this, and need a step by step guide.

Comment: What did you try? What errors did you get?

Answer (score 1):

Please try to restrt cups:

```
sudo systemctl restart cups
```

If after this printing will start working you'll need to install cups-browsed:

```
sudo apt-get install cups-browsed
```

Without cups-browsed cups.socket is unable to listen port 631 right after boot.

This problem persists even on Lubuntu 15.04 Live CD, but not on Ubuntu or Kubuntu. I spent about hour to find this solution.

Comment: afaik `cups-browsed` is used for printers using bonjour (network printers) how is that going to work here? Also, I doubt restarting the cups daemon will help...

Answer (score 1):

Drive for your printer [Lexmark Support](http://support.lexmark.com/index?productCode=LEXMARK_PRO715&page=product&searchid=1353749843550)

1. Open a terminal
2. `wget http://downloads.lexmark.com/downloads/pssd/PPD-Files-LMADI.tar.Z`
3. `tar xf PPD-Files-LMADI.tar.Z`
4. Open a browser and open the URL `http://localhost:631/admin`
5. Select *Administration* and *Add Printer*
6. Select *AppSocket/HP JetDirect*
7. Replace *printer_hostname* with the `socket://<your_printer_hostname>:9100`
8. `Continue`
9. Fill out the form
10. `Continue`
11. Choose the PPD file *Or Provide a PPD File*
12. Select a PPD file from here `<your_download_path>/ppd_files/GlobalPPD_1.4`
13. `Add printer`

That's all